# How to deploy automatically from github to ec2?

Tags: github, amazon-ec2, web-deployment, continuous-deployment, aws-code-deploy

How are you?
I am aws beginner so I don't know well how to set aws configration.
I am going to deploy MEAN stack project from github repo to aws ec2.
But I don't know how should I do it.
So, I need a help of someone who is familiar with this.
Thank you.

Comment: This may help: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/codedeploy/latest/userguide/integrations-partners-github.html